# Maven в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

Допустим создал я создал проект в среде `IntelliJ IDEA` не maven-проект и работаю над ним. Через какое-то время я решил, что хочу пользоваться `maven`'ом через среду разработки так, как если бы я это сделал создав maven-проект. Есть ли какие-нибудь способы подключения к проекту `maven` ?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA - среда нацеленная на разработку Java-приложений, разве нет ? Maven - средство сборки Java-приложений, разве нет ? Я же не указываю метку типа "Озеро Лох-Несс".

Comment: Вам нужно добавить зависимость из maven?

Comment: Herrgott, да, зависимости из Maven и собирать проект им же.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, ой, простите за дерзость.

Comment: Минут 15 назад сам гуглил как из мавена зависимость в intellij idea добавить :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтоб собирать проект `maven`'ом, надо добавить необходимые `pom.xml` файлы, ну и структуру проекта, желательно привести к `maven`'овской.

Для примера допустим ваш код лежит в папке `my-project`. Создаём `pom.xml` в корне этой папки:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
  <name>My Fancy Project</name>
  <version>0.0.1</version>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Здесь указываем все необходимые зависимости -->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Редактируем структуру проекта:

- java-код бросаем в `my-project/src/main/java`
- ресурсы в `my-project/src/main/resources`
- код тестов в `my-project/src/test/java`
  и т.д.

Если `maven-plugin` уже стоит, открываем вкладку `Maven Projects` и добавляем проект, указав путь.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы добавить зависимость из `Maven` репозитория, нужно:

1. Зайти в <kbd>Settings</kbd>-><kbd>Plugins</kbd> и установить всё что связано с `Maven`
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> - находим `Modules` слева и нажимаем на вкладке `Dependencies` зеленый плюсик <kbd>Library...</kbd> -> <kbd>From Maven</kbd>

Comment: Получилось. Но все еще не понятно как задать настройки maven (которые обычно задаются в pom.xml) и как собрать проект maven'ом...

Comment: А вы как собираете проект в jar ?

Comment: @faoxis там же где `Modules` только слева выбираю `Artifacts`, указываю модуль. Потом `Build Artifacts`